# C# app.config files and UAC

Tags: c#, app-config, uac

I started out with my application writing the config to the registry like I did years back with UAC wasn't around.

Turned out this wasn't a good idea so I moved to the `app.config` file and found that this is having issues as well with UAC.

The configuration I have for the application is machine specific; individual users do not have their own configuration and the rest of the apps including the service all drive off the single configuration file.

If I try updating this file in the program files\myapp folder it gets denied.

What is everyone else doing for a scenario like this where there needs to be a single configuration file?

I should also mention that this configuration needs to be updated from within my applications.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting UAC issues with an `app.config` - can you expand on this? What errors/exceptions/behavior do you see?

Comment: @Oded Wouldn't you get issues writing to the file if the app.config is installed in Program Files?

Comment: @BrianV - It is no clear whether the updates are done manually or programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the Common Application Data folder, this is where most new applications store data which works with UAC.

You can get this with the following code:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

To view all options for special folders you can check this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

The most common options would be the following:

**Application Data** - The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data for the current roaming user.

**Common Application Data** - The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by all users.

**Local Application Data** - The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by the current, non-roaming user.

Comment: Or `CommonApplicationData` if it is to be shared across multiple users.

Comment: @DaveShaw - Thanks, just noticed myself and amended.

Answer (score 0):

You should be storing your users' settings in `app.config` you should be using `user.config`. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Any machine-wide configuration files should be stored in:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

Files in Program Files shouldn't be modified except when the application is installed/updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need with a WPF application.  What I do is the following:

1. Install the application with a boiler-plate configuration file.
2. When the app runs, it checks for a config file in the user's App Datadirectory for configuration files, if they're not present it copies the default boiler-plate config files from the install directory.
3. I then do any first-run initialization stuff that is needed.

I started out using the .NET ConfigurationManager, but I switched over to a plain old XML files because it was simpler and my requirements were basic.